# Library to check if cron schedule is monotonic or not

Tags: library, scheduling, cron

I want to implement a feature based on if a given cron schedule is monotonic or not, e.g.
`0 0 * * *` is running every day at 00:00, whereas `0 0 * * 2,3` is not monotonic, given that the interval is not constant.

It is not sufficient to check for a comma, since `0 0 31 * *` is also not monotonic, and neither is `0 * * 1 *` for example.

I'm currently writing this with lots of if/else statements, and while it works, is there a simpler way to do this? Is there a cron schedule library which has a function that given a cron schedule e.g. `* * * * *` and will tell me if it's monotonic or the period if it exists?

There are other cron schedule libraries e.g. [cron-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron-parser). However the only libraries i've found are ones that only return the next/last dates, and ones that turn it into a human readable schedule (e.g. `every minute`).

Language is less important to me, since essentially these string manipulation libraries are often ported to/from other languages and I could build a port if needed.

Comment: thanks, the edit was very helpful